# VBA Add second Sheet with same Name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a CommandButton which opens a UserForm and create a copied Sheet with the name of the ComboBox Value.

This is My Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    [UserForm1].Show                                       ' Open UserForm
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True         ' Unhide Sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
    Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")                ' Copy Sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Name = ComboBox1.Value                              ' Name Sheet

    [UserForm1].Hide                                       ' Close UserForm
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False        ' Hide Sheet again

End sub
```

Now my problem is, if there are two machines with name "Machine Type 1" Excel gets an Error. So what do i have to change in my code, that the second sheet would named e.g. "Machine Type 1 (2)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure i did. But none of there solutions could help me with my problem. They only asks how the code should look to check if there is a sheet with this name, but not how to name it like **Name (2)**

Comment: @diem_L So to make sure i understand, what you're looking for is code to rename a worksheet like `Name (2)`, is that correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg I have Sheet 1, named **machine type 1**, now i want to copy Sheet 1 and name it **machine type 1 (2)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If IsSheetThere(ComboBox1.Value) Then 'if some sheet with chosen name already there
        Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Copy Before:=Sheets(10) ' copy the existing sheet
        With ActiveSheet 'reference just copied sheet
            .UsedRange.Clear 'clear its content
            Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") ' copy Sheet1 content and paste into it
        End With
    Else 'otherwise
        Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' make a copy of "Sheet1" sheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = ComboBox1.Value 'and rename it as per chosen name
    End If
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Function IsSheetThere(shtName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsSheetThere = Not Sheets(shtName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

the code line:

```
Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Copy Before:=Sheets(10) ' copy the existing sheet
```

is the one that leaves Excel the burden of somehow "counting" the number of already existing sheets with the chosen name, and name the new one appropriately

Comment: @diem_L any feedback?

Comment: Sorry i was out of office .. i tried it. Error "Sub or Function is not defined" appears. I´m totally new to VBA so i´m not sure how to solve this

Comment: see edited code where I added the Function `IsSheetThere()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Sub. It checks if a sheet name has already been used in the given workbook by calling the below function. If the name is already in use, it appends " (2)" to the end of the name. If you try to add the same name again, it will append " (3)" and so on.

```
Sub copy_ActiveSheet_and_rename(name As String, wb As Workbook, aftersheet As Variant)
    'name = what you want to name the sheet

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    
    If Len(name) > 26 Then name = Left(name, 26) 'Cutting text that is too long prevents sheet naming errors. Cutting to 26 characters allows for up to 99 sheets with the same name and a number in the parenthesis
    
    If sheet_name_exists(name, wb) Then
        
        Do While sheet_name_exists(name & " (" & i & ")", wb)
    
            i = i + 1
        
        Loop
        
        wb.ActiveSheet.Copy after:=aftersheet
        wb.ActiveSheet.name = name & " (" & i & ")"
        
    Else 
    
       'the below If-block prevents errors when the user enters a new sheet name that contains incompatible characters, replacing them with a dash ("-")

        If InStr(name, ":") <> 0 Then
            
            name = Replace(name, ":", "-")
            
        ElseIf InStr(name, "\") <> 0 Then
        
            name = Replace(name, "\", "-")
            
        ElseIf InStr(name, "/") <> 0 Then
        
            name = Replace(name, "/", "-")
            
        ElseIf InStr(name, "?") <> 0 Then
        
            name = Replace(name, "?", "-")
            
        ElseIf InStr(name, "*") <> 0 Then
        
            name = Replace(name, "*", "-")
            
        ElseIf InStr(name, "[") <> 0 Then
        
            name = Replace(name, "[", "-")
            
        ElseIf InStr(name, "]") <> 0 Then
        
            name = Replace(name, "]", "-")
    
        End If
        
        wb.ActiveSheet.Copy after:=aftersheet
        wb.ActiveSheet.name = name
    
    End If

End Sub


Function sheet_name_exists(name As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
    
        If sheet.name = name Then
            sheet_name_exists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    
    Next sheet
    
    sheet_name_exists = False

End Function
```

here's an example of how to use the sub:

```
Sub test()
    copy_ActiveSheet_and_rename "example name", Workbooks(1), Sheets(1)
    'This copies the ActiveSheet to Workbooks(1) after Sheets(1) and names the copied sheet "hi" - if "hi" is an existing sheet name in Workbooks(1), then it will be named "example name (2)".
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

*Technically* this isn't an answer to this question... **but it's better** because it will help you solve this and many other coding tasks *on your own*.

There is a simple way to create VBA code for most basic tasks.

If there's something Excel can do that you want to be able to do programmatically, just **Record a Macro** of yourself performing the action(s), and then *look at the code* that Excel generated.

I have a terrible memory, I can't remember commands I used yesterday.  So it's not only quicker and less frustrating for others for me to figure it out myself, but the more often I do that, the quicker I'll learn (without asking others to do the thinking for me on a basic question).

I fact, I'm guess that the majority of veteran VBA coders learned at least partly by analyzing recorded macros.  I know I did.

[image: img]

Comment: I know the "record macro" function .. use it all the time. But it won´t help me with this problem. :/